# Trying to startx as user (non-root)

Tags: xorg, xfce

I'm trying to `startx` as user. I am only able to `startx` as `sudo`. More specifically, I'm trying to get pulseaudio to work with xfce4.

I get an error as follows.

```
xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/user/.Xauthority
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sudo` is likely configured not to change the `$HOME` environment variable. Meanwhile `startx` (or at least, the X-server process that it spawns) wants to write an authentication cookie to `$HOME/.Xauthority`. The net result is that `sudo startx` will leave a root-owned `.Xauthority` in your user's home directory - which the user then cannot write to because of its ownership and permissions, so that `startx` *without* sudo fails.

If that's what has happened, you will need to correct the ownership (or simply delete) the root-owned `.Xauthority` file so that normal `startx` can succeed. For example

- switch to a CLI virtual terminal using (for example) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
- log in using your regular user credentials
- `rm ~/.Xauthority`

See also [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)